# How to create a cross-platform multiplayer game without internet access

Tags: android, ios, networking, cross-platform, multiplayer

I'm working on a cross-platform multiplayer game on android and ios.
I need to create a direct network connection between devices without a main server to be able to play without any internet access (e.g. in the metro).

I already tried this kind of game named "[Skies of Glory](http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/social-gaming-network-launches-first-cross-platform-mobile-game-to-enable-live-iphone-to-android-gameplay-over-3g-wifi-and-bluetooth-98598769.html)" where the link between players were performed directly without internet access. Such as computer games, client players can see and connect on a game server created by one of players.

I was unable to find a "free" game framework able to provide this kind of network feature so I try to find out a standardized way to see host servers and etablish a communication without any user prompt thru a wireless connectivity (wifi or bluetooth). iOS and Android are separate worlds but most of network standards are supported by both platforms.

> > So how do it ?

I already excluded solutions:

- Android's WIFI direct: not compatible with iOS and available on 4.x so it's too limited.
- OSI's high level protocols because it suppose to be in the same managed network (so impossible in metro)

My leads

- Turn one of the devices as a router but without user action.
- Piconet technology if it's available on both OS.

If anybody have another idea ....

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you could try using Bonjour http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software) https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/networking.html but there is a reasonable amount of your own programming that would be needed to build what you need.

On Android you might be able to use zeroconf http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking if you can find a suitable existing port or port it yourself using the NDK.